# пару строчек из C# в Java

Tags: java, c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, как этот метод поиска переписать на Java?

```
var reg = string.Format(".*({0}).*", texbox.Text);
Regex any = new Regex(reg);
var mf = a.Split('\n');
textblock.Text = string.Empty;
    foreach (var f in mf)
          if (any.IsMatch(f))
             textblock.Text += f + Environment.NewLine;
```

Вот мой вариант

```
String reg = String.format(".*%S.*", Pattern.quote(edittext.getText().toString()));
Pattern any = Pattern.compile(reg);
String[] mf = str_data.split("\n");
textview.setText("");
for (String f : mf) {
    if (any.matcher(f).matches()) {
        textview.append(f + "\n");
    }
}
```

Но результат не выводится. Похоже, ошибка в условии. Понятия не имею, как его записать эквивалентно коду на шарпе.

Comment: а что за ошибка в результате?

Comment: @abbath0767 не показывает в текствиев совпадающие паттерну строки str_data

Comment: мне кажется, или вы забыли скобочки в регулярке перенести? `".*({0}).*"` => `".*(%S).*"` В остальном вроде все нормально

Comment: @rdorn сделал со скобками, все равно либо последний элемент показывает либо ничего

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так,

```
String regex = String.format(".*(%s).*", Pattern.quote(edittext.getText().toString()));
String[] array = str_data.split("\n");
textview.setText("");
for (String str : array) 
   if (Pattern.matches(regex, str)) 
        textview.append(str + "\n");
```

Comment: Все равно в текствиев показывает либо ничего, либо последнюю строчку str_data, на шарпе прекрасно выводит по строчкам элементы в которых есть совпадение паттерну

Comment: очень странно, приведите пример, на каких строках это не работает